# Live data feed isn't coming in HighChart

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I am trying to add live value to highchart from a sensor to create live data feed.

It is working if I am giving data manually but it isn't working when sensor data is coming.Datas are saving in database but they are not showing on the chart.

Please suggest me if there any other way.

add_data.php

```
<?php
session_start();
    // Connect to MySQL
    include './connection.php';

    // Substring function definition

    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
    {
        $string = ' ' . $string;
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($ini == 0) return '';
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string, $ini, $len);
    }    


    // Collect value datas from packet using substring

    $packet=$_GET["data_packet"];

    $temp_s = floatval(get_string_between($packet, 'ttt', 'ppp'));
    $pressure_s = floatval(get_string_between($packet, 'ppp', 'end'));
    $device = get_string_between($packet, 'dev', 'ttt');

    //convert to float

    if($temp_s!=0 && $pressure_s!=0  && $device!=0)
    {
    if ($device==1)
    {

    $SESSION["temp"] = $temp_s;
    $SESSION["pressure"] =$pressure_s;
        $query = "INSERT INTO machine_1 VALUES('".$SESSION["temp"] ."','".$SESSION["pressure"]."',DEFAULT)"; 
                include './press_m1.php';   
                include './temp_m1.php';
                //echo $temp;

    }

    elseif($device==2) 
    {
        // Enter datas into machine 2 table 
        $_SESSION["temp1"] = $temp_s;
    $_SESSION["pressure2"] =$pressure_s;
        $query = "INSERT INTO machine_2 VALUES ('".$_SESSION["temp1"]."','".$_SESSION["pressure2"]."',DEFAULT)";    
        include './press_m2.php';   
        include './temp_m2.php';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Eror:404";
    }

    }
    // Execute SQL statement

    if(!mysqli_query($con,$query))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
    mysqli_close($con);   
?>
```

temp_m1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php   

        header("Content-type: text/json");
                // The x value is the current JavaScript time, which is the Unix time multiplied by 1000.
                $x = time() * 1000;
                $y = $_SESSION["temp"];
                // Create a PHP array and echo it as JSON
                $ret = array($x, $y);
                echo json_encode($ret);

?>
```

press_m1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php

        header("Content-type: text/json");
                // The x value is the current JavaScript time, which is the Unix time multiplied by 1000.
                $x = time() * 1000;
                // The y value is a random number
                $z =$_SESSION["pressure"];
                // Create a PHP array and echo it as JSON
                $retn = array($x, $z);
                echo json_encode($retn);

?>
```

chart.php

```
<?php
include './header.php';
?>
    <?php
include './site_top.php';
?>
        <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
        <?php
        include './menu.php';
        ?>


    <script>
        var chart;
        var chart1; // global

        /**
         * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout to request again
         */
        function requestDataOne() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'temp_m1.php', 
                success: function(point) {
                    var series = chart.series[0],
                        shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20

                    // add the point
                    chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);

                    // call it again after one second
                    setTimeout(requestDataOne, 1000);   
                },
                cache: false
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'temp',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                    events: {
                        load: function() {
    chart = this; // `this` is the reference to the chart
    requestDataOne();
}
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Live Temparature data'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150,
                    maxZoom: 20 * 1000
                },
                yAxis: {
                    minPadding: 0.2,
                    maxPadding: 0.2,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value',
                        margin: 80
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Temparature',
                    data: []
                }]
            });     
        });
         // global

        /**
         * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout to request again
         */
        function requestDataTwo() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'press_m1.php', 
                success: function(point) {
                    var series = chart1.series[0],
                        shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20

                    // add the point
                    chart1.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);

                    // call it again after one second
                    setTimeout(requestDataTwo, 1500);   
                },
                cache: false
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'pres',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                    events: {
                        load: function() {
    chart1 = this; // `this` is the reference to the chart
    requestDataTwo();
}
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Live Pressure data'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150,
                    maxZoom: 20 * 1000
                },
                yAxis: {
                    minPadding: 0.2,
                    maxPadding: 0.2,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value',
                        margin: 80
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'pressure',
                    data: []
                }]
            });     
        });
        </script>

        <div class="wrapper row4">
        <div id="container" class="clear"> 
        <div class="row">
        <div id="temp" > </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div id="pres" ></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

         <?php
        include './footer.php';
        ?>
```

Comment: How your "point" looks like in your json, which you get from ajax?

Comment: it is good when i am manualy taking data like taking data in for example ...../add_data.php?data_packet=dev1ttt38ppp13.48end but it isn't working when i am connecting with sensor.sensor data is storing on database but not showing on the browser

Comment: But I would like to know how your data looks like